# jquery ajax not firing after disconnect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trap network disconnects, and then restore the ajax long polls when the service is restored. So code like this:

```
var test = function() {
    if (Socket !== undefined && Socket.readyState != 4){
        console.log ("function aborted "+Socket.readyState);
        Socket.abort();
    }

    console.log("in x");
    Socket = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/json/data",      
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data, status, jqXHR ) {
            //process returned data
            console.log("In success");
            if (jqXHR.status == 200 || jqXHR.status == 204) {
                    test();
                }
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("in complete "+status+":"+error);
        },
        error: function( xhr, status, error ){
            console.log("err status="+status);
            console.log("err error="+error);

            setTimeout(function(){ test()},5000);
      } 
    });
};
```

So the weird thing is that it works, but it takes a few minutes for the success method to actually fire.

If I disconnect the service, the error method fires, and the subroutine is executed every 5 seconds waiting for the service to come back. When the service comes back, I see the 'function aborted' line in the console, but then nothing for a few minutes. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

The logs from Chrome:

```
json(%27GET%27,%27/json/data%27) net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
send @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:4
ajax @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:4
test @ x.js:
(anonymous) @ x.js:
i @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:2
fireWith @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:2
ready @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:2
K @ jquery.1.12.4.min.js.gz:2
x.js:err status=error
x.js:err error=
x.js:in complete error:undefined

x.js:function aborted 0
x.js:in x
x.js:In success 
x.js:in x
x.js:in complete nocontent:undefined
```